# Name Space in XMLTABLE function

Tags: xml, web-services, namespaces, wsdl, hana

I have following xml document stored in table

```
<ARSoapOut xmlns:soap=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/>
<ARResponse xmlns=http://company.com/path>
    <ARResult>
        <diffgram xmlns:diffgr=urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1 xmlns:msdata=urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata>
            <NewDataSet xmlns=>
                <FinAccountsReceivable diffgr:id=FinAccountsReceivable1 msdata:rowOrder=0>
                    <SiteID>
                        10001
                    </SiteID>
                    <UnitName>
                        1
                    </UnitName>
                    <Tenant>
                        Doe, John 
                    </Tenant>
                    <Company>
                        ABC
                    </Company>
                    <Balance>
                        46.7600
                    </Balance>
                </FinAccountsReceivable>
            </NewDataSet>   
        </diffgram>
    </ARResult>
</ARResponse>
```

When I execute below query, I got no result.

```
XML_TABLE = SELECT * FROM XMLTABLE (XMLNAMESPACE(DEFAULT 'http://company.com/path')
  'ARSoapOut/ARResponse/ARResult/diffgram/NewDataSet/FinAccountsReceivable' PASSING XML_VALUE
COLUMNS 
SiteID NVARCHAR(5) PATH 'SiteID',
UnitName NVARCHAR(2) PATH 'UnitName',
Tenant NVARCHAR(50) PATH 'Tenant',
Company NVARCHAR(20) PATH 'Company',
Balance DECIMAL(13,2) PATH 'Balance'
);
```

I am not sure what should I parse to the namespace clause. Please help

Comment: How do you execute that query? Which program is going to interprete that? From your question the document could be in any table (Excel, SQL, ...?) but the query does not look like SQL...

Answer (score 1):

Your example has several issues:

**Invalid XML**

All namespace declarations need to be quoted correctly, for example: `xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"`, `xmlns=""`.

**XML Formatting**

Whitespace inside of tags is considered to be part of the value by HANA. That is why, for example, your `SiteID` value does not fit inside an `NVARCHAR(5)` column.

**XML Namespaces**

The path expression does not take namespaces into consideration.

### Solution

Here is a working example:

```
SELECT * FROM XMLTABLE (XMLNAMESPACE('http://company.com/path' AS 'company'),
  '/ARSoapOut/company:ARResponse/company:ARResult/company:diffgram/NewDataSet/FinAccountsReceivable' PASSING '
<ARSoapOut xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <ARResponse xmlns="http://company.com/path">
        <ARResult>
            <diffgram xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
                <NewDataSet xmlns="">
                    <FinAccountsReceivable diffgr:id="FinAccountsReceivable1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                        <SiteID>10001</SiteID>
                        <UnitName>1</UnitName>
                        <Tenant>Doe, John</Tenant>
                        <Company>ABC</Company>
                        <Balance>46.7600</Balance>
                    </FinAccountsReceivable>
                </NewDataSet>   
            </diffgram>
        </ARResult>
    </ARResponse>
</ARSoapOut>'
COLUMNS 
SiteID NVARCHAR(5) PATH 'SiteID',
UnitName NVARCHAR(2) PATH 'UnitName',
Tenant NVARCHAR(50) PATH 'Tenant',
Company NVARCHAR(20) PATH 'Company',
Balance DOUBLE PATH 'Balance'
);
```